# The plural form of One

Tags: grammatical-number

We are doing online marketing and we have a campaign for a smartphone where we say
“If we send you one, will you review it for us?”

Using “one” fits this case perfectly as “smartphone” is singular.
Let’s imagine we need to come up with a similar phrase for “headphones” or “earbuds”. How would this sound if these were “headphones/earbuds” instead of smartphones?

“If we send you , will you review  for us?”

Any ideas?

Comment: The standard term is "a pair of headphones".

Comment: 'If we send you a set' perhaps.

Comment: Or just "if we send you a pair".

Comment: Agreeing with Peter Shor, “send you a pair” is the idiomatic phrase you are looking for in relation to earphones, earbuds or headphones. “Set” is certainly possible but not nearly as idiomatic in my experience. For example, “a pair of glasses/spectacles” never “a set of glasses”. A “set” of something is more likely to be applied where there are more than two (eg: a set of screwdrivers, a set of knives).

Answer (score 2):

The most general word to insert here is ***some***:

> If we send you **some**,  will you review them for us?

The pronoun "some" is useful because it can stand in for a mass noun or count noun. Just as for "one", if the noun is already known, you can omit it in the request.

> Hi, I work for a whiskey manufacturer. If we send you some, will you review it for us?
>
> We make custom metal straws.  If we send you some, will you review them for us?

If you want to emphasize that there are exactly two, there's no reason not to use "two".

> If we send you **two**, will you review them for us?

Also, some of the comments correctly suggest "a pair":

> If we send you **a pair**, will you review them for us?

However, these can carry an implication that a thing comes in matched pairs, or that you need both to use them properly. Just using "a couple" carries no such implication.

Comment: Headphones do come in matched pairs (one for each ear) and you need two to use them properly.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, but you cannot answer this question completely with just "a pair" -- and IMO "some" is still better.

Comment: "Some" works for whiskey, where "a pair" clearly doesn't. For headphones (which I think is the example the OP is most interested in) I prefer "a pair", since "some" might be interpreted as several pairs of headphones.

Answer (score 0):

From a commercial-industrial standpoint, I would (at least in my industry sector) use the term "unit of".  To add more specificity, while still being able to retain the same word-choice, you can say, e.g., `If we send you *a retail unit of* ... , will you review ... for us?`; for the latter part of the sentence, I would reference the item(s) in question as "the product" or "the merchandise".  So in the case of your examples listed, a) a single-unit mobile device and b) a pair of headphones, both would fit under a "retail unit" heirarcially-speaking, i.e., the entirety of the contents as assigned and traceable to each respective UPC code.

Following GS1's [guidance](https://resources.gs1us.org/GS1-US-Data-Hub-Help-Center/File-Repository%3FCommand%3DCore_Download%26EntryId%3D3910&ved=2ahUKEwigx9qa7JjnAhUkHDQIHQkoDWoQFjABegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw0eThE69ZHNZrZL9pOFX6FV), you would reference them as `eaches`, but this may sound strange or incorrect to recipients whom aren't familiar with the technical vernacular.  You can also refer to their [guidance](https://resources.gs1us.org/GS1-US-Data-Hub-Help-Center/File-Repository%3FCommand%3DCore_Download%26EntryId%3D4061&ved=2ahUKEwigx9qa7JjnAhUkHDQIHQkoDWoQFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw2xmIdev1QM8xrsThyGVy7H) in regards to "product packaging level".